# Finding $U(\mathbb{Z}[i])$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I will put my way here, the way that I'm not sure about, and wait for good suggestions :)

Let $a+bi$ be a nonzero element of $\mathbb{Z}[i]$. For $a+bi$ to be a unit, there should be another nonzero element $c+di$ in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ where $(a+bi)(c+di)= 1$.

so this system is then obtained:

$ac-bd=1$

$ad+bc=0$

Since we have that $a+bi\neq 0$, so **$a\neq 0$ or $b\neq0$**.

We have 3 cases here:

First one: if $a=0$,

then $bd=1$ and so $b=\pm1$ and $d=\pm 1$.

Second one: if $b=0$,

then $ac=1$ and so $a= \pm1$ and $c= \pm1$.

Third one: if $a\neq 0$ and $b\neq0$:

We have from the second equation of the system above that $d=\frac{-bc}{a}$, but $d$ is an integer, so we have 2 cases here, first is that $a=b$ then $d=-c$, and this will give, from the first equation of the system above that $a=\frac{1}{2c}$ which is not an integer, so this case is excluded. Second one is that $a=c$, then $d=-b$ and so, from the first equation of the system $c^2 + b^2 =1$ which gives either $c=0$ and $b=\pm1$ or $b=0$ and $c=\pm1$. Then finding $a$ and $d$ from the system above, we conclude that

$U(\mathbb{Z}[i])=$ {$\pm1, \pm i$}.

In the third case I put, I feel like it's not correct to decide that if $d=\frac{-bc}{a}$ and $d$ is an integer, then either $b=a$ or $c=a$ without knowing that this fraction can't be simplified more. Any suggestions for improvements are welcomed.

Comment: If $z$ and $w$ are complex numbers then $|zw|=|z|\,|w|$.

Comment: YES, but I'm looking for an answer without using norms. @DavidC.Ullrich

Comment: Solving these equations will involve $a^2+b^2$, which is the norm.

Answer (score 0):

The equation $ac−bd=1$ means a and b are coprimes.

We want $\frac{-bc}{a} \in \mathbb{Z}$. Then, if $a \neq +-1$, then a|c, because we know a does not divide b.